# ASM Visitor to remove unreachable code

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-bytecode

I'm trying to get a way of detect dead code and remove it from bytecode using ASM.
I'm following [ASM 4 Guide](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf), and in page 119 is stated a dead code removal visitor as this:

```
public class RemoveDeadCodeAdapter extends MethodVisitor {
  String owner;
  MethodVisitor next;
  public RemoveDeadCodeAdapter(String owner, int access, String name,
      String desc, MethodVisitor mv) {
    super(Opcodes.ASM4, new MethodNode(access, name, desc, null, null));
    this.owner = owner;
    next = mv;
  }
  @Override public void visitEnd() {
    MethodNode mn = (MethodNode) mv;
    Analyzer<BasicValue> a =
        new Analyzer<BasicValue>(new BasicInterpreter());
    try {
      a.analyze(owner, mn);
      Frame<BasicValue>[] frames = a.getFrames();
      AbstractInsnNode[] insns = mn.instructions.toArray();
      for (int i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i) {
        if (frames[i] == null && !(insns[i] instanceof LabelNode)) {
          mn.instructions.remove(insns[i]);
        }
      }
    } catch (AnalyzerException ignored) {
    }
    mn.accept(next);
  }
}
```

Also, I'm trying to call this visitor using the following code:

```
public class RunDeadCodeAdapter {

  public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
    ClassVisitor cv = new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM4) {

      String owner;

      @Override
      public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName,
          String[] interfaces) {
        owner = name;
      }

      @Override
      public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature,
          String[] exceptions) {
        TraceMethodVisitor tmv = new TraceMethodVisitor(null, new Textifier());
        return new RemoveDeadCodeAdapter(owner, access, name, desc, tmv);
      }
    };
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader("com/mypackage/locator/DeadClass");
    cr.accept(cv, 0);
  }
}
```

The code sample that I'm using is:

```
public boolean myDeadStatementsMethod(){
    int x = 10;
    if (true){
      x += 20;
      System.out.println(x);
      return true;
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("true is not true");
    }
  }
```

In theory, the line `throw new RuntimeException("true is not true");` can be considered unreachable code, since it will never get executed. The problem with this approach is that the statement `mn.instructions.remove(insns[i])` is never get touched. I don't know the reason, since we have a unreachable statement on that method. Do you guys see anything that is wrong with that approach?

Comment: You don’t find dead code because there is no dead code. The `throw new RuntimeException("true is not true");` is already removed by the Java compiler.

Comment: So, is there situation where this Adapter should be used or it would never be used? And what if I want to detect which lines are unreachable code? Only if I go with AST instead of instrumentation?

Comment: It’s mainly useful as post-processing after other byte code transformations, if dead code might occur as byproduct of these transformations. The line to instruction mapping is compiler dependent and not necessarily covering all lines, e.g. `javac` associates multi-line expressions with the starting line only.